# Should you avoid mixing column and parameter comparisons in the ON statement of a JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge

While trying to optimize a stored procedure which used a MERGE I stumbled onto this article. How should I interpret the bold statement saying to not include comparisons to constants?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx

> Specify only search conditions in the ON  clause that determine the criteria for matching data in the source and target tables. That is, specify only columns from the target table that are compared to the corresponding columns of the source table. **Do not include comparisons to other values such as a constant.**

Does that mean I should avoid an ON statement that looks like this?

```
ON [Source].[CategoryId] = [Target].[CategoryId] AND [Source].[Color] = @Color
```

Does this suggestion apply to just MERGE or for all kinds of JOINs?

Comment: Interesting.  I don't know if this is specifically for the `merge`, but it is bad advice in general (after all, such a comparison is immensely useful with outer joins).  I'm quite curious if a SQL Server guru can explain it.  Personally, I would write the statement both says (use a subquery for the filtering), look at the execution plans, and see if there really is a difference.

Comment: My assumption would be that this is referring to linking on JUST a constant: i.e., it's a bad idea to link Table1 to Table2 on 1=1, because you receive a Cartesian product.  I use the `ON Table2.Value = Constant` frequently with something like a `LEFT JOIN`, though in most circumstances that is accompanied by a linking criteria that, as recommended, compares a column value in the target table to a corresponding value in the source table.

Comment: The docs go on to say "Parameterize all literal values in the ON <merge_search_condition> clause and in the WHEN clauses of the MERGE statement." so perhaps it's ok?

Comment: And reading just above maybe the explanation is "The query optimizer does not apply the simple parameterization process to MERGE statements. Therefore, MERGE statements that contain literal values may not perform as well as individual INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements because a new plan is compiled each time the MERGE statement is executed."

Comment: @PaulWhite . . . I wish the merge required the syntax to be `full outer join` to make the issue clear.  If you give a short answer here referencing that one, I know I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are OK and are recommended.

You should avoid joining using conditions such as ON 1=1

> Query performance may be improved because the frequency of query compilations and
> recompilations are reduced. The query optimizer does not apply the
> simple parameterization process to MERGE statements. Therefore, **MERGE
> statements that contain literal values may not perform as well** as
> individual INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements because a new plan is
> compiled each time the MERGE statement is executed.
>
> **Parameterize all literal values in the ON clause** and in the the WHEN clauses of the MERGE statement. For example, you can incorporate the MERGE statement into a stored procedure replacing the literal values with appropriate input parameters.